# How to solve 504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT error in vercel deployment

Tags: timeout, runtime-error, vercel, nextjs-dynamic-routing, getserversideprops

I have deployed my next js project in vercel it's showing 504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT error on those pages where i have added getServerSideProps function. I am not calling any api request on this getServerSideProps.I am just using this function so that i can't get undefined query values when refreshing the page.

Error image is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvdgF.png)

My code in which page this error is showing,

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

Everything is working fine in localhost but when i deployed my project in vercel it's giving me this timeout error only on those pages where i have used this getServerSideProps. I had already checked after removing the getServerSideProps and after deploying it's wokring fine in vercel but i am getting undefined value of the queries. How can i solve this problem?

I am expecting not to get this error and also not gettiing undefined value of queries after refreshing.